# Dynamics CSS file in component

Tags: angular, dynamic, components, stylesheet

I want the users of my app to have the ability to chose a theme. Therefore I prepared several scss stylesheets which differ in some sort.
I now need to load the according stylesheet due to the selected theme. I did not find any working solution on the web nor on stackoverflow.

I tried to build a **component for each theme** including the according scss in the styleUrls property and using **dynamic component loader**. I need **view encapsulation to set to none**. Due to that the styles are not removed if the component gets destroyed. Is there any way to delete styles set by a component with encapsulation set to none?

Or is there any other way to set scss stylesheets dynamically?

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643042/load-css-file-dynamically-for-theming ?

Comment: does not work with scss

Comment: Am I right that the style tags for components being destroyed should be removed from head even if ecapsulation is set to none? https://github.com/juleskremer/angular/commit/385ed90ac373c0347ea88fe38685405c01ba1a58

Answer (score 0):

You can use bind to ngClass of a parent component.  Example:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div [ngClass]="theme">
      <form>
        <label for="theme">Choose Your Theme</label>
        <select name="theme" id="theme" (change)="onThemeSelected($event)">
          <option value="theme1">Theme 1</option>
          <option value="theme2">Theme 2</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      <p>Content:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [``]
})
export class AppComponent {
  theme = 'theme1'

  onThemeSelected(e) {
    this.theme = e.target.value;
  }
}
```

styles.scss

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

@import './themes/theme1';
@import './themes/theme2';
```

themes/theme1.scss

```
.theme1 {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

themes/theme2.scss

```
.theme2 {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

Source code here: https://github.com/bwhiting2356/angular-themes

Comment: this way I would not be able to style e.g. the body tag differently

Comment: Is there anything in your app that is outside of an angular component?

Comment: nope but I use predefined scss files which rely on body classes ... it would be possible to rewrite yes but is there no way of loading stylesheets dynamically? importing all themes in on big large stylesheet can't be the only way to go?

Comment: I don't know, sorry.